# Could not save posted file exception while uploading an image to media library that ends with (number).extension

Tags: media-library

When I upload an image to media library that ends with (number).extension Sitecore gives an error - log looks like below.

No error if it ends with just () or (letter) or if (number) has a letter after it only in the very specific setup with (number).jpg. Any ideas?

Adding () to InvalidItemNameChars does the trick but maybe there are better options?

> 2968 11:54:07 ERROR Could not save posted file: myimage file
>   (2100).jpg Exception: System.AggregateException Message: One or more
>   exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the
>   'item:creating' event. Source: Sitecore.Kernel    ved
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName,
>   Object[] parameters, EventResult result)    ved
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[]
>   parameters)    ved Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemCreating(Object
>   sender, ItemCreatingEventArgs args)    ved
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.DataEngine_CreatingItem(Object sender,
>   ExecutingEventArgs1 e)    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler1
>   handlers, Func2 argsCreator)    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand2.RaiseExecuting(Boolean&
>   cancelled)    ved Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand2.CanExecute()
>   ved Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand2.Execute()    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.CreateItem(String itemName, Item
>   destination, ID templateId, ID newId, DateTime created)    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.DoCreateAndReturnItem(String
>   itemName, Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId, DateTime created)
>   ved Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.CreateItem(String itemName,
>   Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId, DateTime created,
>   SecurityCheck securityCheck)    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.CreateItem(String itemName, Item
>   destination, ID templateId, ID newId, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
>   ved Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.CreateItem(String
>   itemName, Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId, SecurityCheck
>   securityCheck)    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.CreateItem(String itemName,
>   Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId)    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.CreateItem(String itemName, Item
>   destination, ID templateId, ID newId)    ved
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.AddFromTemplateCommand.(String , Item
>   , ID , ID )    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.AddFromTemplateCommand.DoExecute() 
>   ved Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.AddFromTemplateCommand.DoExecute()
>   ved Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand2.Execute()    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.AddFromTemplate(String itemName,
>   ID templateId, Item destination, ID newId)    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.AddFromTemplate(String
>   itemName, ID templateId, Item destination, ID newItemId)    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.AddFromTemplate(String itemName, ID
>   templateId, Item destination, ID newItemId)    ved
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Add(String name, TemplateID templateID, ID
>   newItemID)    ved Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Add(String name, TemplateID
>   templateID)    ved
>   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.CreateItem(String itemPath,
>   String filePath, MediaCreatorOptions options)    ved
>   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.AttachStreamToMediaItem(Stream
>   stream, String itemPath, String fileName, MediaCreatorOptions options)
>   ved Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.CreateFromStream(Stream
>   stream, String filePath, MediaCreatorOptions options)    ved
>   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUploader.UploadToDatabase(List`1 list)
>   ved Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUploader.Upload()    ved
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save.Process(UploadArgs args)

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you on? Have you submitted a ticket to Sitecore support? Unless you've customized the upload process somehow, this seems like a Sitecore bug.

Comment: Have you tried the same on a vanilla Sitecore instance using same Sitecore version?